# adding element to the end of sequence in C struct

Tags: c, struct, sequence, typedef, seq

```
    #include "seq.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    typedef struct stack_node {
       ETYPE data;
       struct stack_node *prev, *next;
    }NODE;

    struct seq_struct {
       // "Container" struct
       NODE* top, *bottom;
       int size;
    };

/**
* DESCRIPTION:  adds a new element to the "back" of
*  the seq
*
*   [2 4]
*        add_back 7
*            [2 4 7]
*
*
*/
void seq_add_back(Seq seq, ETYPE val){
NODE* endq = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
   endq->next =NULL;

   endq->prev = seq->bottom;
   endq->data = val;

   seq->bottom->next=endq;
   seq->bottom = endq;

   seq->size++;
   return;
}
```

I need your help in understanding what is wrong with my code. It doesn't add a new element to the sequence at the end like it should been.

I have another portion of code, for deleting and adding elements to the front of of the sequence and it works fine, also to note print function is fine too. everything beeing initialized to NULL, and zero at the start of the program.

Comment: This is correct code., `Seq` is  typedef of struct `seq_struct` ?

Comment: Add other part of code, probably some other part of code corrupts you sequence list that you calls before calling `seq_add_back()` function

Comment: Q: Is seq is a pointer to your "Sequence" record?  You're not passing a copy (a copy that's never being updated), are you? Q: What happens with the *first* record added?   Definitely step through seq_add_back() under the debugger: perhaps the *ACTUAL* problem you're experiencing lies elsewhere.  IMHO...  PS: You don't need a "return" in a void function.

Comment: I only see one flaw: no special handling if the sequence you pass in is empty. Can you show the program that calls this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first: `bottom` pointer in the `seq_struct` should be initiated to NULL

second: before calling

```
seq->bottom->next=endq;
seq->bottom = endq;
```

you have to check if `seq->bottom` is not `NULL`. so your code should looks like this

```
if (seq->bottom != NULL)
    seq->bottom->next=endq;
seq->bottom = endq;
```

You have to take in account the first element to insert in your linked list with your function `seq_add_back()`.

So you have to update your `seq->bottom` also if it's the first elemenent to insert in the linked list.

The `seq->bottom` should be initiated to NULL.

and you have to add the following code at the end of your function `seq_add_back()`:

```
if (seq->top == NULL)
    seq->top = endq;
```

So as summary your function should look like this:

```
void seq_add_back(Seq seq, ETYPE val){
   NODE* endq = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
   endq->next =NULL;

   endq->prev = seq->bottom;
   endq->data = val;

   if (seq->bottom != NULL)
      seq->bottom->next=endq;
   seq->bottom = endq;

   if (seq->top == NULL)
      seq->top = endq;

   seq->size++;
   return;
}
```