# adding element to the front of sequence in C struct

Tags: c, struct, sequence, typedef

```
typedef struct stack_node {
   ETYPE data;
   struct stack_node *prev, *next;
}NODE;

struct seq_struct {
   // "Container" struct
   NODE* top, *bottom;
   int size;
};

void seq_add_front(Seq seq, ETYPE val){

    /* create a node to be added to the front of the sequence */
    NODE* topq = malloc(sizeof(NODE));

    topq->data = val;

if(seq->top==NULL){
    topq->prev=NULL;
    topq->next=NULL;
    seq->top = topq;
    seq->bottom=topq;

}
   else{
    topq->prev=NULL;
    topq->next=NULL;

    seq->top=topq;
    seq->bottom=topq->next;
    //seq->top=topq;


   }

   /* increment the size */
   seq->size++;

}
```

I need your help in understanding what is wrong with my else-statement. I cannot figure out how to keep the previous value if(seq->top!=NULL).

My starting problem was [adding element to the end of sequence in C struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19287686/adding-element-to-the-end-of-sequence-in-c-struct) and it was overwriting by this function. Now i rewrote it, and need to figure out a way to keep a value of seq->bottom while adding new values.

Comment: You do not even have an `else` statement in that code example.

Comment: @nixeagle sorry my mistake. now I just renamed what should be else-statement.

Comment: So, does it work now? You did copy the *real* code in and not retyped it, correct? If not, do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
   else {
    topq->prev=NULL; // make sure our prev is null
    topq->next = seg->top; // set our next to the current top
    seg->top->prev = topq; // set the current top to point back to us
    seq->top=topq; // set current top to be us
   }
```

Note that bottom does not need to change in this else clause

Comment: yes, that looks like what it should be.
But this still doesnt work. No mater how many times i call this function, I get only last call(input value). All the previous values are overwritten?!

Comment: Must be something else in your program.

Comment: Yes, I did figure it out, it was a problem with print_function for my sequence.
Thank You very much! =)